# Type cast for custom classes

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I'm creating a project where different custom types and classes might depend on each other.
I have a type named `Gram`, and I want to create custom type casting for this type. For example, I have another class - `Kilogram` and when I trying to `Gram` to `Kilogram`, it must use Gram value and divide it by 1000.
Or, maybe, it would be more reasonable using classes instead of types. But even in classes I don't have  an idea how to implement type casting

Comment: Do you know that TS is about structural typing? It means two types are equals if their shapes are equal. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system

Comment: It would be more reasonable to use classes.

Comment: If you look for something like CPP's auto cast then there's nothing like this in TS.